# how to progressbar based on cmd output in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am bluilding an application these days on vb.net using VS2019. One of the app's features is a button that users will click, choose to run batch file.

The app run batch file. batch file runs on the background when it's started. The app has a textbox in which users will be able to see CMD's output.

I have added a progressbar in the app. i want to get batch file progress to vb.net progressbar .

anyone help me how to get batch file progress to progress to vb.net progressbar ?

```vb
Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
Dim path As String = Environ("temp") & "\" & New Random().Next(1, 546546) & ".bat"
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(path, False)

Try
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    sw.Write(tempcode)
    sw.Close()
    psi = New ProcessStartInfo(path)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
    cmd.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: A title and some code is NEVER an adequate question. You MUST provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. The fact that you have no badges indicates that you did take the site tour when prompted and now you don't know how to write a proper question. Spend some time in the Help Center to learn what's acceptable and what's not.

Comment: What does the batch file do?  A progress bar suggests you've got some defined hard limit to the process being performed in the batch file.  Perhaps a better solution might be to display an animation rather than a progress bar?

Comment: Hi Hursey my batch file is doing for cleaning temp in my pc...

Comment: What, specifically, is the output of the batch file and what indicators does it contain for your application to determine the progress? Does it display a percentage? The status of discrete steps completed? The number of files/bytes deleted vs. the total to be deleted? You might have an easier time just scrapping the batch file and having your VB.NET code perform the cleanup itself.  By the way, make sure you prefix another user's name with the @ sign (e.g. @Hursey) so they'll be notified of your comment.